# implode multidimensional array

Tags: php

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {   
   $id = $row['id'];
   $col1 = $row['name1'];
   $col2= $row['name2'];
   $col3= $row['name3']; 

   ${"$id"} = array("$col1","$col2","$col3");
   ${"$s".$i}[] = ${"$id"};
 }
```

This is just a breif example of what i'm trying to accomplish, `$i` is incremented somewhere else. I'm trying to implode the arrays in the array.  So below I have imploded the main array but how do I implode the other arrays?

```
for($i=0;$i<11;$i++) {
  $array = ${"s" . $i};
  $outcomes = implode("",$array); //implodes main array
}
```

Comment: if you want to echo some variable, just echo it. why implode?

Comment: i have it structured a certain way.. i only posted this as an example my real code is alot longer.  I just need to know how to echo out the values of the arrays in an array.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: Implode data from a multi-dimensional array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16710800/php-implode-data-from-a-multi-dimensional-array)

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you are trying to achieve here, but does this help?

```
function recursive_echo ($arr, $spacing = 0) {
  $padding = ($spacing) ? str_pad('', $spacing) : '';
  foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
    if (is_array($val)) {
      echo "{$padding}{$key}:<br />\n";
      recursive_echo($val, $spacing + 2);
    } else {
      echo "{$padding}{$val}<br />\n";
    }
  }
}
```

This function just echoes out the data, but it illustrates how to recurse through a multi-dimensional array where the number of dimensions is unknown.