# Implode on a nested array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to implode every "a_skill" in this array into a string. Usually I would do `implode(", ", $my_array);` but this is nested. Is there an easy way to handle this?

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [email] => don.pinkus@gmail.com
            [a_skill] => test
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [email] => don.pinkus@gmail.com
            [a_skill] => testerrrr
        )

)
```

From PHP's array docs, array_keys looks promising but I can't get it to work.

Comment: Why dont you just run a loop and grab the value into an array that way?

Comment: possible, but with PHP's slough of array functions figured there was an easy one

Comment: Check out the @Msencenb answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16710800/implode-data-from-a-multi-dimensional-array). `json_encode($array)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using PHP 5.5 then you can use [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) like follows:

```
$a_skill_array = array_column($my_array, 'a_skill');
echo implode(', ', $a_skill_array);
```