# Imploding multi-dimensional array with recursive function

Tags: php

below is my array...

```
  Array(

    [Open+Sans] => Array
      (
        [0] => normal
        [1] => lightitalic
        [2] => light
        [3] => semibold
      )

    [Nova+Script] => Array
      (
        [0] => normal
      )

    [Nova+Slim] => Array
      (
        [0] => normal
      )

    [Old+Standard+TT] => Array
      (
        [0] => normal
      )
  )
```

I want the keys to be imploded with | and child array to be imploded with commas, the final expected string will be like below:

Open+Sans:normal, lightitalic,light,semibold | Nova+Script:normal | Nova+Slim:normal | Old+Standard+TT:normal

thanks for your time..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Implode data from a multi-dimensional array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16710800/implode-data-from-a-multi-dimensional-array)

Comment: why not use json_encode()? then you'll end up with a string in a common and widely used format rather than your own custom format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ich guess this should work

```
$output;
foreach($input_array as $k => $v){
    output.= $k.":";
    output.= implode(",",$v);
    output.= "|";
}
```

Comment: worked like charm.. highly appreciated your input.. the only thing was to check recursive is its array and implode again.. but I modified and worked as desired.. cheers