# Array to string conversion - Associative Array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, pdo

I use this code below to parse a question and its choices.

```
$entries = preg_split('/(?=[a-z\d]+\.(?!\d))/', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
$arrAnswers = array();
$arrQuestions = array();
$id = 0; //Assuming your table is empty

foreach($entries as $entry) { //Loop through the grabbed records
  if(is_numeric(substr($entry, 0, 1)) === true) { //Is it a question?
     $id++;     
     $arrAnswers[$id] = array();
     $arrQuestions[$id] = '(\''. $entry .'\')'; 
  } else { //Ok, it's a possible answer to a question
     $arrAnswers[$id][] = '(\''. $entry .'\', '. $id .', 0)';
  }
}
      echo "<pre>";
        print_r($arrQuestions);
      echo "<pre>";

      echo "<br>";

      echo "<pre>";
        print_r($arrAnswers);
      echo "<pre>";
```

Which returns these array result:

```
$arrQuestions output

Array
    (
        [1] => ('1. What is foo?')
        [2] => ('2. What is foo?')
    )

$arrAnswers output
    Array
    (
        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => ('a. foo1', 1, 0)
                [1] => ('b. foo2', 1, 0)
                [2] => ('c. foo3', 1, 0)
                [3] => ('d. foo4', 1, 0)
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [0] => ('a. foo1', 2, 0)
                [1] => ('b. foo2', 2, 0)
                [2] => ('c. foo3', 2, 0)
                [3] => ('d. foo4', 2, 0)
            )

    )
```

My code for the insertion of records:

```
try {
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
// set the PDO error mode to exception
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$strDbQuery = "INSERT INTO `question` (`q_name`) VALUES ". implode(", ", $arrQuestions);
$strDbQuery_2 = "INSERT INTO `answers` (`choices`, `question`, `correct`) VALUES ". implode(", ", $arrAnswers);
// use exec() because no results are returned
$conn->exec($strDbQuery);
$conn->exec($strDbQuery_2);
echo "New questions uploaded successfully";
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo $strDbQuery . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
echo $strDbQuery_2 . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}

$conn = null;
```

I printed the the message of the transaction and on the insertion of the answers, the value being inserted is an array. I used the function `implode()` but it is still treated as  an array.

```
INSERT INTO `question` (`q_name`) VALUES ('1. What is foo1?'), ('2. What is foo2?')  
INSERT INTO `answers` (`choices`, `question`, `correct`) VALUES Array, Array
```

What should I do guys?

Comment: edit with the output of   print_r($arrAnswers);

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer I updated my question, terribly sorry if my output was not clear, thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: implode() doesn't work for multidimensional arrays. You can try this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16710800/implode-data-from-a-multi-dimensional-array

Comment: @rodrigovr I appreciate your help, this is informative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: More generic

```
$strDbQuery_2 = "INSERT INTO `answers` (`choices`, `question`, `correct`) VALUES ";

for($i = 1; $i <= count($arrAnswers); $i++) {
    $strDbQuery_2 .= implode(", ", $arrAnswers[$i]) . ', ';
}

$strDbQuery_2 = substr($strDbQuery_2, 0, -2) . ';';
```

Comment: This really helps and thorough!