# multidimensional array implode whole inner array elements function in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => b
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => c
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => d
            [1] => e
            [2] => f
        )

)
```

I want to convert above two dimensional array into following array using implode or any other function in php

```
Array
(
[0]=>a,b
[1]=>c
[2]=>d,e,f
)
```

Comment: have you tried anything

Comment: possible duplicate of [Implode data from a multi-dimensional array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16710800/implode-data-from-a-multi-dimensional-array)

Comment: i tried implode function using foreach its give output like this a,b,c,d,e,f

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `loop` and `implode` them and store them -

```
foreach($yourArray as $key => $array) {
    $yourArray[$key] = implode(',', $array);
}
```

Or `array_map` also help -

```
$new = array_map(function($array) {
    return implode(',', $array);
}, $yourArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$newArray = array();
foreach ($array $k => $v) {
    $newArray[$k] = implode(",", $v);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change your existing array,

```
array_walk($your_array, function(&$v){
    $v = implode(',', $v);
});
```

If you want a new array,

```
$new_array = array_map('implode', $your_array,
                 array_fill(0, count($your_array), ',')
             );
```