# PHP Imploding Multidimensional Array

Tags: php, arrays

I need to implode an multi-dimensional array in a string using implode, i tried using the `array_map` shown here: [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16710869/2717182) but i failed.

Array:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [code] => IRBK1179 
        [qty] => 1 
    ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [code] => IRBK1178 
        [qty] => 1 
    ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
        [code] => IRBK1177 
        [qty] => 1 
    ) 
)
```

Desired Output:

```
IRBK1179:1|IRBK1178:1|IRBK1177:1
```

Comment: use foreach and implode inner with `:` and outer with `|`.

Comment: create a new array using foreach and then implode that

Comment: tq for reformating @Thamizhan

Comment: Don't blindly `implode` - it will fail if the order of array keys change. Only implode arrays if the order does not really matter, when using numeric indices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use foreach and `implode()` inner array with `:` and then `implode()` new array with `|`. Try below code.

```
$arr = Array ( 
        0 => Array ( 'code' => 'IRBK1179','qty' => 1 ),
        1 => Array ( 'code' => 'IRBK1178','qty' => 1 ),
        2 => Array ( 'code' => 'IRBK1177','qty' => 1 ) );
$newArr = array();
foreach ($arr as $row)
{
    $newArr[]= implode(":", $row);
}

echo $finalString = implode("|", $newArr);
```

**Output**

```
IRBK1179:1|IRBK1178:1|IRBK1177:1
```

**Working Online Demo: [Click Here](https://eval.in/565866)**

Use `explode()` to get back array from string.

Try below code.

```
$finalString = "IRBK1179:1|IRBK1178:1|IRBK1177:1";
$firstArray = explode("|", $finalString);
foreach($firstArray as $key=>$row)
{
    $tempArray = explode(":", $row);
    $newArray[$key]['code'] = $tempArray[0];
    $newArray[$key]['qty'] = $tempArray[1];
}

print_r($newArray);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [code] => IRBK1179
            [qty] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [code] => IRBK1178
            [qty] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [code] => IRBK1177
            [qty] => 1
        )

)
```

**Working Demo : [Click Here](https://eval.in/569251)**

Comment: that is exactly what i mean at comment. Great!!

Comment: glade to help you. Thanks for correct and UV. :) @hafizyBaharudin

Comment: @RuchishParikh, how about to explode it back to the array from the string created?

Comment: Check my edited code. I have explode it back and convert string to array. @hafizyBaharudin

Answer (score 3):

As i commented out, use the `implode` and `foreach`. for inner array use `:` and for outer array use `|`.

```
$str = array();
foreach($arr as $val){
    $str[] = implode(":", $val);
}
echo implode("|", $str); //IRBK1179:1|IRBK1178:1|IRBK1177:1
```

Answer (score 2):

Both other answers given by [Frayne](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37045991/4198099) and [Ruchish](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37045979/4198099) are correct.

Here is another alternative using [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php).

```
$arr = [[ 'code' => 'IRBK1179','qty' => 1 ],
        [ 'code' => 'IRBK1178','qty' => 1 ],
        [ 'code' => 'IRBK1177','qty' => 1 ]];

echo implode('|', array_map(function ($val) {
  return $val['code'].':'.$val['qty'];
}, $arr));
```

**Output:-**

```
IRBK1179:1|IRBK1178:1|IRBK1177:1
```

Comment: Yes. It is. I have edited it as per your requirement and pointed out by Frayne Konok :-)

Comment: Note that `implode()` does not look at the keys that are being imploded. So if by whatever effect the order of the inner keys `code` and `qty` are reversed, `implode()` will happily create a string with the wrong order. Bottom line: only use `implode()` on numeric arrays where the order of entries does not matter.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution using `array_reduce` function:

```
// $arr is the initial array
$result = array_reduce($arr, function($a, $b){
   $next = $b['code'].":".$b['qty'];
   return (!$a)? $next : (((is_array($a))? $a['code'].":".$a['qty'] : $a)."|".$next);
});

print_r($result);
```

The output:

```
IRBK1179:1|IRBK1178:1|IRBK1177:1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version:

```
<?php

$arr = [
    0 => ['code' => 'IRBK1179', 'qty' => 1],
    1 => ['code' => 'IRBK1178', 'qty' => 1],
    2 => ['code' => 'IRBK1177', 'qty' => 1],
];

$str = implode("|", array_map(function ($value) {return implode(":", array_values($value));}, array_values($arr)));

var_dump($str); # "IRBK1179:1|IRBK1178:1|IRBK1177:1"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array ( 
                '0' => array ( 
                    'code' => 'IRBK1179', 
                    'qty' => '1' 
                ), 
                '1' => array ( 
                    'code' => 'IRBK1178', 
                    'qty' => '1' 
                ), 
                '2' => array ( 
                    'code' => 'IRBK1177', 
                    'qty' => '1' 
                ) 
);

$string ='';
foreach($array as $key=>$value){

    $string .= $value['code'].':'.$value['qty'].'|';

}
echo $string;
```