# implode for multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

//for below array i need the values of name to be semi-colon separated
output should be 
monica;pradnesh

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Monica
                    [address] => Surat
                    [mobile_number] => 8956231245
                    [telephone_number] => 
                    [email_id] => monica@kritva.com
                    [DOB] => 0000-00-00
                    [gender] => female
                    [PAN_number] => ASDFG4567A
                    [customer_type] => SALES
                    [dependency_type] => Retail
                    [cust_id] => 9055954
                    [state] => Gujarat
                    [city] => Surat
                    [zipcode] => 752852
                    [exist_from] => 2016-12-20
                    [edit_date] => 0000-00-00
                    [staff_id] => 
                    [BA_id] => 
                    [id] => 31
                    [nationality] => Indian
                )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => Pradnesh
                [address] => Surat
                [mobile_number] => 8956231245
                [telephone_number] => 
                [email_id] => pradnesh.valapkar@kritva.com
                [DOB] => 0000-00-00
                [gender] => male
                [PAN_number] => GHJKL9876S
                [customer_type] => NRI
                [dependency_type] => BA
                [cust_id] => 2736738
                [state] => Gujarat
                [city] => Surat
                [zipcode] => 895623
                [exist_from] => 2016-12-21
                [edit_date] => 0000-00-00
                [staff_id] => 
                [BA_id] => 5822043
                [id] => 33
                [nationality] => Indian
            )

    )

)
```

Comment: What is your expected outpu ?

Comment: What is the resulting data set format? How would you like the output?

Comment: output should be like:- monica;pradnesh

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implode data from a multi-dimensional array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16710800/implode-data-from-a-multi-dimensional-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first extract all the name to array $names, then use implode like this:

```
$names = array_map(function($v){return $v[0]['name'];}, $array);
implode(',', $names);
```

Comment: @Tiger yeah, In the question there is only 0.

Answer (score 1):

Might be this can show you direction.

```
<?php 
$data = array(
    array(
        array(
          'name' => 'Monica',
          'address' => 'surat'
        ),
        array(
          'name' => 'Priya',
          'address' => 'surat'
        )
    ),
    array(
        array(
          'name' => 'Pradnesh',
          'address' => 'surat'
        ),
        array(
          'name' => 'test',
          'address' => 'surat'
        )
    )
);

array_map(function ($entry) {
    echo implode(';',array_map(function ($d) {
       return $d['name'];
    }, $entry));
}, $data);
?>
```

**Output**

```
Monica;PriyaPradnesh;test
```