# Php - How to convert multiple key values array to | (Pipe) Separated string

Tags: php, arrays, string, pipe

I am working on one project with multiple array operations.

I have one variable called **$product_attributes** and it contains below array as value.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Applications
            [1] => Steel; PVC; Std. Wall
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Blade Exp.
            [1] => 0.29
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Fits Model
            [1] => 153
        )
)
```

Now i want to convert it into **| (Pipe) Separated String** like below:

```
Applications=Steel; PVC; Std. Wall|Blade Exp.=0.29|Fits Model=153
```

Below is what **i have tried:**

```
$tags = implode('|',$product_attributes);
echo "Output".$tags;
```

But it returns output as below:

```
OutputArray|Array|Array|Array|Array|Array
```

Comment: this may helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16710800/implode-data-from-a-multi-dimensional-array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution using `array_map` and `implode` functions:

```
$result = implode("|", array_map(function ($v) {
    return $v[0] . "=" .$v[1];
}, $product_attributes));

print_r($result);
```

The output:

```
Applications=Steel; PVC; Std. Wall|Blade Exp.=0.29|Fits Model=153
```