# Unable to return value after implode

Tags: php, arrays, string, multidimensional-array

This is my array

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => SC1MTTCS6J1WK
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => SC1MTTCSHJ1WK
    )
)
```

But when I try to implode them using

```
$in_text = implode(",", $myArray3);
```

I can't get the value instead I got this:

```
Array,Array
```

Please assist thank you.

Comment: Kindly visit this link.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16710800/implode-data-from-a-multi-dimensional-array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the simple code, try this

```
$in_text = implode(',',array_map('implode',$myArray3));
echo $in_text;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
$in_text = '';
foreach ($myArray3 as $key=>$val){
    if(is_array($val)) {
        $in_text .= ($in_text != '' ? ',' : ''). implode(",", $val);;
    } else {
        $in_text .= ($in_text != '' ? ',' : ''). $val;
    }
}
echo $in_text;
```

**PS**: This will work upto two dimensional array.

Comment: Thanks alot, only need up to 2d array.

Answer (score 0):

You call `implode` on an array of array, which result the `Array, Array`. You can call like this,

```
implode(",", array_column($myArray3, 0));
```