# Array Special Characters to String

Tags: php

I am creating password generator, I am dealing at the moment with array of special characters to transfer them into string. I have special characters saved in cvs file, using as array to slice based on how many special characters should be in password, then I want to make them string and concatenate with numbers and letters.

```
    $list = './SpecialChar.csv';
    $e = array_map('str_getcsv', file($list));

    //$nRange telling how many characters should be slice
    $nRange = $length-($numb*2)-$specialChar;

    shuffle($e);
    $s = array_slice($e,0,$nRange);
    $sString = implode(" ",$s); //does not work
    $sString = htmlentities(implode(" ",$s)); //does not work
```

Comment: I am getting error Notice: Array to string conversion when using implode

Comment: Can you give us the output of `var_dump($s)` before the `implode`?

Comment: Is $s multidimensional array ?

Comment: I would really advice against using the .csv file to store your list of special chars. Also, I would try to find some meaningful names for the variables.

Comment: array(2) { [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "-" } [1]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "*" } }

Comment: @angel.bonev it is multidimensional array

Comment: @NKU implode as you can check in https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php implodes string not array so if you want to implode subarray you can use array_map or something, I'll add a comment in a while

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16710800/implode-data-from-a-multi-dimensional-array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[implode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) only accepts string so if you try to convert array to string this will return you "string(5) "Array"" no matter what it's in the array

```
var_dump((string)["T","E","S","T"]);
```

So when you try to implode multidimensional array you will get something like this

```
    $test = [["-"], ["*"]];
var_dump(implode(" ", $test)); //THIS WILL GIVE YOU Notice: Array to string conversion when using implode , but it will return string(11) "Array Array"
```

If dimensional are only two  you can use [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

```
$test = [["-"], ["*"]];
var_dump(implode(" ", array_map(function ($row) {
                        return is_array($row)?implode($row):$row;
                    }, $test))); //returns string(3) "- *"
```

Comment: thank @angel.bonev, I am still trying to figure then how to concatenate strings of $letters and $numbers. ```
            $n = range(0,9);
            shuffle($n);
            $numbers = array_slice($n,0,$nRange);
            $numbersString = implode(" ",$numbers);```, because $test is still just array, looks like I have safe all special characters in array, but it does not work, if I am creating regular array

Comment: @NKU Implode expects one dimensional array you can't concatenate multydimensional arrays only with implode, it converts every element to string, so you can foreach all you data and merge it into one dimensional array or use something like array_map