# Store array inside of array in db using laravel

Tags: laravel-5

I have a common array from request named complemntartData[]. from that array i get some values.i need to store these data in db table field.i used implode function but it shows array to string conversion.
[image: this is complementaryData]

```
    if($request->input('complementaryData')){
       foreach($request->input('complementaryData') as $name => $value){
          $data = explode ("_", $name);
          $A = [];
          $B = [];
          if($data[0]=="TextField"){
            $B["id"] = $data[1];
            $A["TextField"] = &$B;
            $B["data"] = $value;
           }
           if($data[0]=="Archive"){
              $B["id"] = $data[1];
              $A["Archive"] = &$B;
              $B["data"] = $value;
           }
           if($data[0]=="MultipleChoice"){
              $B["id"] = $data[1];
              $A["MultipleChoice"] = &$B;
              $B["sub"] = $value;
           }
           $eventParticipants->complementaryData = implode(',',$A);
           //dd($eventParticipants->complementaryData);
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
implode(',', $A['Archive']);
```

The error comes from you passing a multidimensional array to implode:
[implode-data-from-a-multi-dimensional-array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16710800/implode-data-from-a-multi-dimensional-array)

Also if you want to store array data in single field, I would rather use [serialize](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php):
serialize($A) can be easily unpacked using the unserialize() function

Comment: i only gets the last if not the all if

Comment: the implode and seralize is working only for the last if

Comment: $complementaryData = [
 "TextField_123" => "hhhhhhh",
 "Archive_131" => "pink.jpg",
 "MultipleChoice_132" => "arar"
]; print_r(serialize(*A));

Comment: You should only get the last one, because you are looping through $request->input('complementaryData') with a foreach. $A = []; shoud be before the foreach loop, if you want all key values in one.

Comment: $A = [];foreach($complementaryData as $name => $value){

Comment: I presume $request->input('complementaryData') is the array in the image. You are looping through it by key value, but your array $A is recreated at the beginning of each loop as an empty array.